# How to read a block of data from file (instead of a whole file) in Swift

Tags: swift

Let's say I've got a file that is 8 bytes long containing only ASCII characters: `brownfox`.

Instead of loading the whole file and working on if, I wan't to load block of 2 bytes `[UInt8]` and do operation on 2-bytes sized blocks, so the operations goes as follow:

1. load `br` from file (and *not* the whole file)
2. do any actions on the data, for example reverse to `rb`
3. save the output to another file
4. repeat for: `ow` `nf` `ox`

Reasoning behind this:
This way if I handle a file that is 1GB of text I don't have to actualy have 1GB of RAM free (or 2GB for input and output file).

This method for files handling is important to me for encryption and sending to cloud solutions.

I'm using this extension:

```swift
extension Data {
    /**
     Consumes the specified input stream, creating a new Data object
     with its content.
     - Parameter reading: The input stream to read data from.
     - Note: Closes the specified stream.
     */
    init(reading input: InputStream) {
        self.init()
        input.open()

        let bufferSize = 1024
        let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bufferSize)
        while input.hasBytesAvailable {
            let read = input.read(buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
            self.append(buffer, count: read)
        }
        buffer.deallocate()

        input.close()
    }

    /**
     Consumes the specified input stream for up to `byteCount` bytes,
     creating a new Data object with its content.
     - Parameter reading: The input stream to read data from.
     - Parameter byteCount: The maximum number of bytes to read from `reading`.
     - Note: Does _not_ close the specified stream.
     */
    init(reading input: InputStream, for byteCount: Int) {
        self.init()
        input.open()

        let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: byteCount)
        let read = input.read(buffer, maxLength: byteCount)
        self.append(buffer, count: read)
        buffer.deallocate()
    }
}
```

But `init(reading input: InputStream, for byteCount: Int)` always goes from 1st byte. How can I read for example from 16th to 20th byte?

Documentation on `InputStream.read(_:maxLength:)`

> From the current read index, take up to the number of bytes specified
>   in the second parameter from the stream and place them in the
>   client-supplied buffer (first parameter). The buffer must be of the
>   size specified by the second parameter. Return the actual number of
>   bytes placed in the buffer; if there is nothing left in the stream,
>   return 0. Reset the index into the stream for the next read operation.

What can I do to **not** reset the index, and get the next operation from the place where the previous ended?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `FileHandle`. You can open the file handle for reading. Then use `seek(toFileOffset:)` to set where you wish to read from. Then use `readData(ofLength:)` to get some `Data`. Be sure to close the file handle when done.

Answer (score 2):

rmaddy's solution worked!

Here's a very rough snippet for anybody that will came here with the same problem. It's not an exact answer, but it shows everything that needs to be done :)

```swift
    func loadInBlocks(path: String) -> [Data] {
        var blocks = [Data]()
        let correctPath = //path to file
        let fileHandle = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: correctPath)

        let dataFromFirstByteTo4thByte = fileHandle!.readData(ofLength: 4)
        blocks.append(dataFromFirstByteTo4thByte)
        fileHandle?.seek(toFileOffset: 4)
        let dataFrom5thByteTo8thByte = fileHandle!.readData(ofLength: 4)
        blocks.append(dataFrom5thByteTo8thByte)
        fileHandle?.closeFile()

        return blocks
    }
```

and the actual usage:

```swift
    func loadBlock(number: Int, withBlockSize size: Int, path: String) throws -> Data {
        let correctPath = path.replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "%20", with: " ")

        guard let fileHandle = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: correctPath) else { throw NSError() }

        let bytesOffset = UInt64((number-1) * size)
        fileHandle.seek(toFileOffset: bytesOffset)
        let data = fileHandle.readData(ofLength: size)
        fileHandle.closeFile()
        return data
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your don't need the call to `seek` since `readData` moves the file pointer and your next read is where it left off.

Comment: You should also revisit your handling of `nil`. You use both `!` and `?` on `fileHandle`. Neither is ideal in this case but at least be consistent.

Comment: Code above was just a proof of concept. Actual code addresses this concerns :) I've did an edit to show how it looks like. And, yes, I know, I could do better than throwing a generic `NSError` :D